# Adding Provided JS (under a directory) in SBT causing unexpected token

Tags: sbt, scala.js

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL]

Invalid character is coming in the generated *-js-deps.js, when I am trying to add a ProvidedJS build.sbt

I tried with 0.6.9 & 0.6.11 
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.11")

jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "js/igniteui/infragistics.core.js"

Any clue why it is adding an invalid character in the generated *-js-deps.js ?

Thanks in advance

PS - I have used the normalized path as per this gissue
https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2358

Comment: That seems to be a byte order mark (aka BOM) that is in the included file (`infragistics.core.js`). Hence, it seems like your file is UTF-16 encoded. Scala.js assumes files to be UTF-8 encoded. Try changing the file to UTF-8 encoding and see if the problem persists. If you absolutely need UTF-16 support, please file an issue.

Comment: $ file -bi infragistics.core.js
**application/octet-stream; charset=binary**

Comment: seems it has some binary data in .js file, tried dos2unix but no luck, trying to encode the file to UTF-8 or ASCII